# Чат на PHP

Tags: jquery, php, ruby, javascript, mysql

Нужно написать чат на php, помогите, пожалуйста!

Мне поставили задачу написать чат на php, ранее с этой задачей никогда не сталкивался. Если быть точнее, то дали два файла (сервер чата - написан на ruby и клиент написан на jQuery, если кому-то интересно могу выложить исходники) и сказали сделать то же самое на php. Но так как я не знаю ruby, то решил писать все с нуля.

Но как уже упоминалось выше, я еще ни разу не сталкивался с подобной задачей, поэтому прощу помощи знающих людей. А именно:

1. Подскажите, пожалуйста, алгоритм работы простого чата на PHP с использованием БД MySQL. Я буду пытаться все сам реализовать, если будут появляться вопросы - буду спрашивать тут.
2. Чат будет частью сайта, как я представляю - сделаю на html формах...

Заранее благодарен всем, кто откликнется помочь советом или подсказками!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я в общем-то, тоже не писал чаты, но по логике, там не должно быть чего-то сложного. Если сказали убрать JS/jQuery, то я бы использовал скрытый iframe, в который target-ом будет отправляться сообщение пользователя, что позволит избежать перезагрузки страницы. Сообщение это вносится в БД, а поле вывода надо просто обновлять с определенным интервалом, вытаскивая последние N записей.

Comment: Нет, мне как раз jQuery убирать не нужно! Нужно серверную часть сделать на PHP, а клиентскую можно на JS/jQuery/Ajax.

Comment: Тогда я не могу понять в чем проблема.

Comment: @eprivalov1 - может вы погуглите? ;)

Comment: Под поле вывода - хоть <div>, хоть <textarea>, да что угодно, под поле ввода - <input type="text">. jQuery/Ajax: 1. функция передающая новое сообщение; 2. Функция обновляющая вывод сообщений с определенной периодичностью (setInterval). В PHP: 1. Функция, которая вносит в БД новое сообщение; 2. Функция, которая вытягивает определенное кол-во последних сообщений. Для привязки сообщений к пользователю - делаем сессии. Что ж тут сложного?

Comment: Спасибо, вроде не так сложно, как показалось в первый раз, утром буду пробовать!

Comment: @eprivalov1 - удачи, в следующий раз, перед тем как задавать такой баянистый вопрос - погуглите, скорее всего, ответы на свои вопросы вы найдете намного быстрее, более того - с примерами кода и развернутыми пояснениями.

Comment: Спасибо, уже нашел, но реализация корявая до безобразия, к сожалению!

Comment: Ну, так подровняйте. Что нам стоит дом построить? ))

Comment: Ок, буду работать напильником!

Answer (score 2):

Может будет интересно: 
[Мощная система для организации чата](http://www.coolwebmasters.com/chat/2272-powerful-chat-system-lesson-1.html).

Comment: Большое спасибо, обязательно посмотрю!

Comment: Посмотрите. Там вроде всего 8 уроков...

Answer (score 2):

Довольно таки не плохой чат, с довольно таки не плохими возможностями — [**MEL.Chat**](http://melnaron.net/projects/melchat) (демо версия не работает).

Скачивайте, устанавливайте, смотрите что да как.

Comment: Большое спасибо, обязательно посмотрю!

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, вам поможет инструмент от Дмитрия Котерова [Realplexor](http://dklab.ru/lib/dklab_realplexor/)

> Dklab Realplexor — это Comet-сервер, позволяющий держать одновремено сотни тысяч долгоживущих открытых HTTP-соединений с браузерами пользователей. JavaScript-код, запущенный в браузере, подписывается на один или несколько каналов Realplexor-а и вешает обработчик на поступление данных. Сервер может в любой момент записать сообщение в один из таких каналов, и оно будет моментально передано всем подписчикам (хоть одному, хоть тысяче), в режиме реального времени и с минимальной нагрузкой для сервера.

Достаточно прост в работе, имеет API для PHP и JavaScript и, в отличии от Node.Js, не требует глубоких познаний в событийной модели программирования. При этом, по сравнению с классическими ajax-чатам, достаточно производителен.

PS Примеры чата есть на сайте по ссылке выше.

Comment: ну прям так уж сотни тысяч? он обошел проблему 10К?
теорию читать надо - реклама все это

Comment: Мопед не мой.

> DmitryKoterov,24 декабря 2009 в 15:27
> Обычный Linux c ulimit -n 1048576 и несколькими listen-сокетами. У меня открылось даже в perl-скрипте 200 тыс. сокетов, это не такое большое значение.

http://habrahabr.ru/post/79189/#comment_2316420

Answer (score 0):

Самый старый чат на РНР (php4) http://php.spb.ru/chat/ 
Сам внедрял в 2004 году. 
Можешь ознакомиться с исходниками для общего понимания.

Answer (score 0):

Если авторизация не нужна, то это дело на пару часов:

На странице вывод чата, форма, дальше POST, фильтрация и запись в БД, состоящую из 2х таблиц **username|text**, дальше редирект на страницу с чатом, обязательно надо использовать 2 разные страницы (одна для просмотра, другая для отправки и редиректа) к примеру chat.php и chat.php?act=post, так как при обновлении страницы форма отправится снова, к тому же такую страницу удобно использовать для вывода ошибок и просьбы авторизоватся.

Ну и потом по нарастающей, нужна авторизация, прикуриваем ее, нужны смайлы, прикуриваем их, нужна динамичность, прикуриваем ajax и тд.